# plot a "list" of densities

Tags: r

I have a data.frame composed of 10 columns and 50 rows. I computed density function, column by column using the apply function. Now I would like to plot the densities I computed  at once.

In other words, instead of plotting...

```
plot(den[[1]]) 
plot(den[[2]]
plot(den[[3]]
```

...I would like to plot all the densities at once.

I suppose I have to use the `lapply` function and probably I have to write a specific function to do this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`latticeExtra` has very handy function, `marginalplot`

```
marginal.plot(DF,layout=c(2,2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this would be helpful

```
set.seed(001)
DF <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(400, 100, 12), ncol=4)) # some data
den<-apply(DF, 2, density) # estimating density


par(mfrow=c(2,2))
sapply(den, plot) # plot each density
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Which gives...

[image]

Giving some names:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 1:length(den)){
  plot(den[[i]], 
       main=paste('density ', i))
}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

If you just don't want all plots in one output you may want to leave `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` out and just run `sapply(den, plot)`

**Edit: Answer for your second question (in the comment)**

```
plot(den[[1]], ylim=c(0,.04), 
     main='Densities altogether') # plot the first density
for(i in 2:length(den)){          # Add the lines to the existing plot
  lines(den[[i]], col=i)          
}
```

[image]

Here is useful using `legend` function to add a legend

```
legend('topright', paste('density ', 1:4), col=1:4, lty=1, cex=.65)
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use `l_ply()` from `plyr`, which is intended to not return output.

Comment: @Bfu38.  Glad to be useful :D

Comment: yes, Jiber, very useful! Just another short question..and if i would like to plot all the densities curves on the same plot?

Answer (score 1):

I think that `lattice` package could be handy:

Following example from Jilber:

```
set.seed(001)
DF <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(400, 100, 12), ncol=4)) # some data
DF <- stack(DF) # to long form

library(lattice)
densityplot(~values|ind, DF, as.table=TRUE)
# or
densityplot(~values, groups=ind, DF)
```

Results are:

[image: Separate densities]

and

[image: Combined densities]